# Problem logging in to gmail with geckofx 45.0

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I am using GeckoFX 45.0 on my project and can not activate it when I try to log on to gmail in my application. How can I overcome this problem?

```
GeckoPreferences.User["intl.accept_languages"] = "tr-TR";
GeckoPreferences.User["javascript.enabled"] = true;
GeckoWebBrowser wb = new GeckoWebBrowser() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
wb.Navigate("https://gmail.com");
```

For image:
[enter link image here](https://ibb.co/i8MMqU)

Comment: can't speak to this specific control, but I know from past experience that gmail and google forms in general, really really hate automated solutions.  Have you had similar issues with other sites requiring login.  Like ymail.com or other login pages?

Comment: I am having trouble with WhatsApp and facebook